# Pass parameters to crud controller Backpack laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

i create button in the line of the table "league"  and when press on it most moved to the table "game" and pass parameter "league_id" to GameCrudController ...
then when i get the "league_id" in setup function on GameCrudController i have problem ,
to find the problem i make error_log on setup function to know what happen ,
i well set the code and some image to show the problem :

added button in the table "league" :

```
$this->crud->addButtonFromView("line", "Games", "games" ,'end');
```

[show button in view league table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GGki.png)

create games.blade.php view in vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\crud\buttons\games.blade.php , and the content is :

```
@if ($crud->hasAccess('games'))
        <a href='{{ backpack_url('game/' . $entry->getKey()) }}' class="btn btn-sm btn-link"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Games</a>
@endif
```

added in the route :

```
Route::crud('game/{league_id?}', 'GameCrudController');
```

and in the setup function on GameCrudController :

```
public function setup()
{
    $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Game');
    $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/game');
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('game', 'games');


    $passed_league_id = \Route::current()->parameter('league_id');
    error_log("test");
    error_log($passed_league_id);
}
```

and in console its access one time to "league_id" and then show empty line after "test" like this :

```
test
3
.
.
.
test
"empty line"
.
.
.
test
"empty line"
.
.
.
```

i don't andurstand why print "test" three times and i can't access the passed_id ?!

Please help. I want to reach for "league_id" to make filter at GameCrudController.
What is the problem in the previous steps and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is normal. 
backpack for Laravel uses ajax to get the data later on.

at the first request: your URL looks like this:

```
/admin/game/1
```

where `1` is `league_id`.

after the first request backpack calls ajax requests to show the data. and looks like it's calling

```
/admin/game/search
```

instead of

```
/admin/game/1/search
```

to repair that you should use `setRoute` correctly:

```
$passed_league_id = \Route::current()->parameter('league_id');
if($passed_league_id != null )
{
    $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/game/'.$passed_league_id);
}
else 
{
    $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/game');
}
```

this way it'll generate the routes correctly and all of you're following ajax requests will be made on the base url

```
/admin/game/1
```